# How to tell which custom React component I clicked?

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I want to make a high-level custom component double clickable. Of course, I want to identify which one of them was double clicked. Using CustomCard from the @mui library, I begin like this:

```
<CustomCard id={playlist.ID} key={playlist.date} onDoubleClick={goToPlaylist}>
```

My first goal is successful: goToPlaylist is called if I double-click anywhere in the "card", which consists of several DOM elements. But my second goal is not. If I look at the details, I get a SyntheticBaseEvent on an object of type img.MuiCardMedia-root.MuiCardMedia-media.MuiCardMedia-img.css-o69gx8-MuiCardMedia-root . But its target attribute gives me an object that has id="" and no key attribute. So how do identify what I have clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would bind the `onDoubleClick` handler to a new inline function, which will in turn allow you to pass the context which is available to you in the scope to the `goToPlaylist` handler. For you, that context you want to pass is `playlist`.

```
<CustomCard id={playlist.ID} key={playlist.date} onDoubleClick={(e) => goToPlaylist(e, playlist)}>
```

Notice that I passed the event and the `playlist` as the *second* parameter. You will need to modify your handler to accept two parameters, the event and the playlist.

Or you could just do `onDoubleClick={() => goToPlaylist(playlist)}` instead which would discard the event, though it's a sort of standard practice to pass both, with the event first. If `goToPlaylist` is called elsewhere though where it's not in response to an event, and really doesn't care about that event, this would also be totally fine.

Note the reason you can't see `key` on the event object is that that is a React prop and the event contains a reference to the HTML element and its attributes. The key never ends up on the DOM node as an HTML attribute, it's just private to Reacts virtual dom model in memory. So you can't access it that way. Now and again you will see code that gets around this by assigning an HTML attribute like `id` and then accessing that from the event, but this is generally an anti-React way of doing things. You have the playlist right there, so you can just pass it. I see you have an `id` assigned, and that's ok, but I wouldn't consume it from the event object for this situation, even if you technically could.

In addition, it's likely your `key` should really also be `playlist.ID`. It's critical that this is unique in the set. If you have more than one playlist with the same date ever, this code would break.